# How to Improve INP Score in Mobile

Tags: wordpress, pagespeed, core-web-vitals, interaction-to-next-paint

I am not able to identify why the mobile INP score of guru99.com is high

I thought Ads the culprit but a page: https://www.guru99.com/wysiwyg-web-builder.html

Which has no ads has still high INP score: https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-www-guru99-com-wysiwyg-web-builder-html/f4hs0ijbyu?form_factor=mobile

Then I thought it is images but https://www.guru99.com/workflows-informatica.html

But this page seems to load fine.

Can you please help identify what should be done?

Answer (score 0):

INP is a measure of responsiveness so in general images do not cause issues (though they can affect the other Core Web Vitals - LCP, and CLS).

When you say a page without ads still has a high INP score you need to be careful what PageSpeed Insight's is showing you here. You are seeing the site-level INP score:

[image: Warning that real user data is for whole origin]

Ads, can be a common cause of INP issues, especially on mobile, as they can involve quite a lot of processing, processing time that is not available for responding to users, so that's not a bad guess.

Ultimately you need to measure INP on your site while doing interactions (see [this document for more information](https://web.dev/diagnose-slow-interactions-in-the-lab/)) or, ideally, [measure the slow interactions from your users to help identify them](https://web.dev/find-slow-interactions-in-the-field/).